# Can TouchBegan work together with gestureRecognizer in same view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I try to implement touchBegan and SwipeGestureRecognizer in the same view but it did not
Detect the swipeGestureRecognizer every touch is call touchBegan so, can it works together?

Comment: Can you please paste some code so we will have a better look?

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive about the SwipeGestureRecognizer but I was able to implement the TapGestureRecognizer along with touchesBegan. I would suggest first commenting out the touchesBegan and seeing if the Swipe is recognized. This would be your starting point. It could be that the swipeGestureRecognizer is not connected to the view or that you did not set setUserInteraction: to YES or TRUE. But once you get the swipe to register. Then uncomment your touchesBegan, and test again. There is also this delegate method that may give you more information:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

Also you can check out: [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
and [UISwipeGestureRecognizer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer)